# concatenate character with numbers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns id, cut_id. For e.g:

```
id  cust_id
1   abc1234
2   abc2345
3   abc5678
```

query to update cust_id as abc-1234 instead of abc1234?

Answer (score 2):

Use `PATINDEX` to search for the start of the numeric character and `STUFF` to insert a `-` in between.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
ID          Cust_ID
----------- --------------------
1           abc1234
2           abc2345
3           abc5678
4           abcde5678
5           a5678
6           abcdef5678
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE Temp SET Cust_ID = STUFF(Cust_ID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Cust_ID), 0, '-')
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Cust_ID
----------- --------------------
1           abc-1234
2           abc-2345
3           abc-5678
4           abcde-5678
5           a-5678
6           abcdef-5678
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
update your_table
set cust_id = stuff(cust_id, 4, 0, '-')
```